# Webpack: Error in multi module not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, path

I'm trying to learn Webpack but I've got an error when I try to do the most simple webpack command so it's very frustating. Here is my error :

```
PS D:\Projets\#Bazar\WebPackTry> webpack src/js/main.js dist/bundle.js
Hash: 67b5c95f9d0dfcab805d
Version: webpack 4.0.0
Time: 227ms
Built at: 2018-2-25 12:41:17
  1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/js/main.js + 1 modules 83 bytes {0} [built]
    | ./src/js/main.js 32 bytes [built]
    | ./src/js/log.js 51 bytes [built]
[1] multi ./src/js/main.js dist/bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.

ERROR in multi ./src/js/main.js dist/bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dist/bundle.js' in ' 
D:\Projets\#Bazar\WebPackTry'
@ multi ./src/js/main.js dist/bundle.js
```

So as you can see I made this command : `webpack src/js/main.js dist/buundle.js` and webpack throw me this error.

I tried with absolute paths and I thought that the name of my path with #Bazar would be the issue.
But even when changing them I've got the same error.

The only way I succeed was when I created myself a dist/bundle.js

But even like these webpack create another file in my dist folder call `main.js`

I tried to follow multiple tutorials butI didn't found any information about this error.

Also this is my project architecture

```
WebpackTry
|-node_modules
|-dist
|-src
|  |-css
|  |-js
|     |log.js
|     |main.js
|index.html
|package-lock.json
|package.json
```

PS: Sorry for my english :/

PS2: I can't post images yet so I had copy / paste my errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read through the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), and set up a webpack.config.js file in your root directory. Also, move all your source files into src/ (including index.html).

The following is a sample webpack.config.js file, customized to fit your current project structure.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 12):

The following is the help message from webpack by typing **webpack --help** in **webpack 4**

```
Usage without config file: webpack <entry> [<entry>] --output [-o] <output>
```

**Notice**: **--output** need to be specified explicitly

---

**Solution:**

```
webpack src/js/main.js --output dist/bundle.js --mode development
```

Add **--output** to it and specify the **mode** option will be ok.

Comment: Thanks, Neven - that was exactly the solution that I needed.